# Using Aeron on same host and media driver count

Tags: aeron

I would like to use Aeron on the same host using IPC as media.
Do I have to run two media drivers or is just one sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use IPC then all communicating clients must be using the same media driver, therefore you only need one.